# Calculating min/max from the terminal in C

Tags: c, assign, infinity

i want to create a program which prints biggest first number and biggest second number when i enter 5 number.(1.value of the number is=0) .there is no problem when i enter 5 numbers bigger than 0, but when i enter 5 numbers smaller than 0 , program prints first biggest number is 0 and second biggest number is 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = 0, first, second, numbercounter = 0;
    first = number;

    while (numbercounter < 5) {
        printf("5 tamsayi girin:", ++numbercounter);
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if (number > first) {
            second = first;
            first = number;
        } else if (number > second)
            second=number;
    }

    printf("En buyuk sayi: %d \n", first);
    printf("En buyuk ikinci sayi:%d \n", second);

    if (first % second == 0) {
        printf("%d, %d'nin tam katidir.\n", first, second);
    } else {
        printf("%d, %d'nin tam kati degildir.\n", first, second);
    }

    if (first == second) {
        printf("%d ve % esittir.\n", first, second);
    } else {
        printf("%d ve %d esit degildir.\n", first, second);
    }
    if (first % 2 != 0) {
        printf("%d tektir.\n", first);
    } else {
        printf("%d cifttir.\n", first);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no integer representation for infinity.  If you want the most negative possible signed integer, use `INT_MIN` from `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: oh thank you, can you explain more or make a sample for me ?

Comment: Ummm... `first = second = INT_MIN;`

Comment: Th title of the question has nothing to do with its content... I updated the title.

Comment: yeah it has extra functions, i am gonna try it

Comment: @Myst How does the title now connect to the content? I don't see any pointers there.

Comment: @thebusybee - I don't know what happened... I updated the title again.

Comment: `second` is uninitialized when used for the first time.

Comment: @Myst: Great, now it's clear. --- Concerning your comment: More exactly: it is read unitialized if the first `if` is `false` on the first loop run. You should make this an answer. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee true :) ... I just noticed JeremyP posted an answer, so I'll move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `first` starts out as `0`. If `number` is negative, `if (number > first)` is false.
- `second` is used uninitialised if `number <= first`.

Use `INT_MIN` for your initial values, this is the most negative integer you can have. Use this declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0, first = INT_MIN, second = INT_MIN, numbercounter = 0;
```

Also get rid of the line

```
    first = number;
```